# My street view alert box has failed to show

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

am working on an android app that uses street panorama, I tried to query for availability of street view from a location before loading the street view but it doesn't work. If I type a valid street view location, it will load, but when I type an invalid location it will fail to show the alert message telling the user that street is not available. Here is the code below.

```
  function codeAddress() {


    var address = document.getElementById('autocomplete').value;
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

       map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);

      var streetViewService = new google.maps.StreetViewService();
      var STREETVIEW_MAX_DISTANCE = 100;

       streetViewService.getPanoramaByLocation(results[0].geometry.location, STREETVIEW_MAX_DISTANCE, function (streetViewPanoramaData, status) {

              if (status === google.maps.StreetViewStatus.OK) {
               panorama.setPosition(results[0].geometry.location);
                  }
              else {
                alert("Street view not available in your location");
                 }
            });
         }

     else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
               }
          });
        }
```

Comment: I tried to copy your code but I can not reproduce it, I mean, the problem should be in other part of your code... (I guess?) I can post my file here if you want.. otherwise, why don't you check to see if there are errors in the console?

Comment: I have checked multiple times, other things are working except when I click the button to perform the search. If I put a valid street view location it works, but an invalid street view location should display an alert

Comment: huh... here is my code.... I paste your code into the sample and it just works... http://jsfiddle.net/t12vhf8q/1/

Comment: can I send the complete code as a new question?